# Change a thread's target core

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu-usage, cpu-cores

What is the way of telling a thread to change the core that it is working on programmatically?

Lets say i am using FX-8150 which has some cores but i want one of my threads to work  in especially the 5.core. Is this possible? If yes, can you give a sample of Java please? The thread may be another process' thread or the current process' thread.

My pseudo example:

```
time interval 1 : my_thread working in first core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 2 : my_thread working in second core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 3 : my_thread working in third core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 4 : my_thread working in fourth core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 5 : my_thread working in fifth core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 6 : my_thread working in sixth core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 7 : my_thread working in seventh core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
time interval 8 : my_thread working in eighth core at 5GHz while other cores are 3.6 GHz
```

All other cores will be needed to be idle.

Comment: This level of architecture specific operations is certainly not a part of standard Java.  If you can do this in C then you may be able to make a JNI call however.

Comment: You saying as library or including c in java?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? I think the OS does this job the best

Comment: I'm saying you can call out to C (or other languages) using JNI and may be able to do what you want.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: Any OS has the ability to separate the single-thread's time to all cores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a library called [Java Thread Affinity](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity) which allows you to assign running threads to logical thread or cores.

In your case, you need to allow one core for the OS as a minimum, and you can reserve all the remaining cores in Linux. The thread library assigns threads to these reserved cores.  The reason you want reserved cpus is to prevent other threads running on that cpu. You can tell the library to assign a thread to a logical cpu, or a whole core.  You can assign threads to be on the same or different core or socket as another thread.

https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity/wiki/Getting-started

The library currently supports Windows and Linux.

Comment: Okay, looking at the pdf file

Comment: Could this be dynamic through the program, like changing a threads core 10-100 times per second?

Comment: In theory, but that could hurt performance considerably defeating the point of doing this. You get the best results by preventing context switching on a cpu to ensure the threads is always running "hot" with a "warm" cache.

Comment: You saying that, when a core is too hot, changes to other core but probably that core is already heated to some degree and cache-faulty is bad? It doesnt copy the cache instantly does it? I mean the l2 or the independent ones.

Comment: I don't mean hot in terms of temperature. I mean hot in terms of the branch prediction, instruction and data caches are all populated with the data they need. Without this a thread can run 2-5x slower.

Comment: Very cool @Peter.  However, you should rename your library to be the `Java Thread Affinity / Premature Optimization` library @Peter.  :-)  I sounds like a recipe for misuse by newbies for sure!  Oh, and congrats on the gold badge for Multithreading.  Well deserved.

Comment: @Gray I would use the word cool as well meaning interesting but rarely useful because it not needed.  The OS Scheduler does a better job in 99% of cases.  You would only using it in rare cases where you need real time.  If misused it could easily do more harm than good.

Comment: Figured you would agree with me @Peter.  Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Windows 7.  Find the process in Task Manager, right click on it, select set affinity, choose which core you want it to use.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/83632-processor-affinity-set-applications.html

**Programatically:**

You can permanently set a program's affinity by creating a .bat batch file in the same folder as the program, with the contents:

```
start /affinity 1 program_name.exe

start /affinity 1 <invoke your_java_program>
```

This will force the program to use only cpu core 0. use ... /affinity 2 ... to specify cpu core 1 etc

You should then modify the program's start-menu and/or desktop shortcut to point to your newly created batchfile.

a tiny drawback is that you will see a small cmd window briefly flash on the screen before your program opens.

for extra performance, you can add /high to give the application a higher cpu priority.

```
start /affinity 1 /high program_name.exe
start /affinity 1 <invoke your_java_program>
```

Comment: I need it programmatically please, lets say changing 100 times per second so heating effect will be separated to all cores rather than single core.

Comment: Changing the affinity by allowing your program to finish and starting the program again 100 times per second would invoke a large overhead that depends on how long it takes your program to begin working.